# How can I add an attachment to an auto-respond email in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Over the next few weeks, I expect a lot of emails requesting a particular form and I would like to set up an auto-respond email that sends over the form to anyone emailing me during this time.

I use Gmail and my laptop is a MacBook Pro.

Is it possible to set up an auto-respond that sends an attachment?

Answer (score 2):

One way around this could be to upload the form to a webserver and include the link to it in the auto-respond email.